# NativeScript Expand Cardview

Tags: android, nativescript, android-cardview, angular2-nativescript, cardview

I am creating a list of cards in a nativescript app using [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-cardview) and I was wondering if it was possible to expand the card on click like the google inbox app animation as shown below

[image]

Comment: Possible? Yes. You would just need to animate the card  on an event using the animation API. I don't have any snippets handy but scaling something to fill the screen isn't too difficult. Use the platform module to find info on the device (for setting the scale/translate). The more important thing is how you define your layout.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried scaling the card but the problem is that the content get scaled along with it. I could post my layout if that would help